# I have already translated the type into int but still suffered a type error (python language)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def get_positive_int():
    while True:
        n = int(input("Height: "))
        if n > 0 and n < 9:
            return n
            
def print(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(" " * (n - i) + "#" * i + " " + "#" * i)
        
def main():
    n = get_positive_int()
    print(n)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and here is my error message:
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Since int(input()) has already translate n into an int I an curious why would n recieve an string?

Comment: Probably related to the input, i.e. check the value that comes out of `input("Height: ")`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have defined a custom function named `print()` and you call `print()` again in the loop. So, in the next recursion call, you call the custom defined `print()` with `str` object in `print(" " * (n - i) + "#" * i + " " + "#" * i)` and `range()` then throws the error since it expects an integer but it got an `str` object.

Change the name of the `print()` method to something else:

```
def get_positive_int():
    while True:
        n = int(input("Height: ").strip())
        if n > 0 and n < 9:
            return n
            
def print_0(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(" " * (n - i) + "#" * i + " " + "#" * i)
        
def main():
    n = get_positive_int()
    print_0(n)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It is therefore recommended to not use the same name for custom defined objects which are already defined in the language.